# Angular Material DatePicker: Month and Day, Exclude Year

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, angular8

How do I create a Month and Day Date Picker in Angular, excluding hide year?

This following link will do a Month and Year picker. I am trying to manipulate it, to do Month and Day. Replacing YYYY with DD is not working.

**Stackblitz:**

https://stackblitz.com/angular/gxymgjpprdy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-views-selection-example.ts

**Real code from Stackblitz:**

**Typescript:**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {MomentDateAdapter, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';
import {MatDatepicker} from '@angular/material/datepicker';

// Depending on whether rollup is used, moment needs to be imported differently.
// Since Moment.js doesn't have a default export, we normally need to import using the `* as`
// syntax. However, rollup creates a synthetic default module and we thus need to import it using
// the `default as` syntax.
import * as _moment from 'moment';
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-duplicate-imports
import {default as _rollupMoment, Moment} from 'moment';

const moment = _rollupMoment || _moment;

// See the Moment.js docs for the meaning of these formats:
// https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};

/** @title Datepicker emulating a Year and month picker */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-views-selection-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-views-selection-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-views-selection-example.css'],
  providers: [
    // `MomentDateAdapter` can be automatically provided by importing `MomentDateModule` in your
    // application's root module. We provide it at the component level here, due to limitations of
    // our example generation script.
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]
    },

    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ],
})
export class DatepickerViewsSelectionExample {
  date = new FormControl(moment());

  chosenYearHandler(normalizedYear: Moment) {
    const ctrlValue = this.date.value;
    ctrlValue.year(normalizedYear.year());
    this.date.setValue(ctrlValue);
  }

  chosenMonthHandler(normalizedMonth: Moment, datepicker: MatDatepicker<Moment>) {
    const ctrlValue = this.date.value;
    ctrlValue.month(normalizedMonth.month());
    this.date.setValue(ctrlValue);
    datepicker.close();
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp" placeholder="Month and Year" [formControl]="date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #dp
                  startView="multi-year"
                  (yearSelected)="chosenYearHandler($event)"
                  (monthSelected)="chosenMonthHandler($event, dp)"
                  panelClass="example-month-picker">
  </mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

I do not want year option below in green, would like to disable year

[image]

**Other Resources:**

https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#watching-the-views-for-changes-on-selected-years-and-months

[Angular Material Date picker disable the year selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54266328/angular-material-date-picker-disable-the-year-selection)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hope you are expecting date format like DD/MMM. If so then change **dateInput** in **display** and **parse** object like below

```
dateInput: 'DD/MMM'
```

Hope this helps.

Here is the stackblitz code.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hw54xf

Answer (score 0):

[image]

> So , first in the html file

```
 <mat-form-field class="mat-50-left" (click)="updateCalendarUI()">
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker_start"
           placeholder="Date de début" required formControlName="dt_start" (click)="picker_start.open();">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix (click)="picker_end.open(); updateCalendarUI()"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker_start startView="year"></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

> in the .ts file

```
       import {DateAdapter, NativeDateAdapter} from "@angular/material/core";
       import * as moment from "moment";

    export class AppDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
       format(date: Date, displayFormat: Object): string {
        // use what format you need
        return moment(date).format('DD MMM');
      }
    }
```

> add in providers

```
  providers: [{provide: DateAdapter, useClass: AppDateAdapter}]
```

> To update calendar UI

```
  updateCalendarUI(): void {

     setTimeout(() => {
       let calendar = document.getElementsByClassName('mat- 
      calendar').item(0);
      if (calendar) {
         calendar['style'].height = '275px';
         calendar['style']['padding-top'] = '15px';
        }
     let header = document.getElementsByClassName('mat-calendar- 
      header').item(0);
      if (header) {
         header['style'].display = 'none';
      }
      let yearLabel = document.getElementsByClassName('mat-calendar-body- 
       label').item(0);
      if (yearLabel) {
          yearLabel['style'].display = 'none';
      }
    }, 1);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html `<mat-datepicker` you have this: `panelClass="example-month-picker"`.
Putting the following in your css will disable the option that you marked with a green box:

````
.example-month-picker .mat-calendar-period-button {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.example-month-picker .mat-calendar-arrow {
  display: none;
}```
````