# how to show only current year in mat-datepicker

Tags: mat-datepicker

I'm using angular material datepicker.But in that datepicker I want o show only current year .. any idea how do I do that ?

You can refer the provided link
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use matDatepickerFilter to filter your date range.

```
<input matInput [matDatepickerFilter]="dateFilter" [matDatepicker]="picker">
```

And you can filter the date range you wants in the dateFilter method.

```
  dateRange = [new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1),
               new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 11, 31)]

  dateFilter= (d: Date): boolean => {
    return (d >= this.dateRange[0] && d <= this.dateRange[1])
  }
```

Comment: Hi Koga .. Thanks for ur reply.. But instead of giving the dates manually can we make it dynamic ??

Comment: new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1),

.getFullYear() will return current yer.
0 for January (Month, starting from 0. So december is equals to 11).
1 for date.

Comment: <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

In ts. file

  minDate =  new Date()
  maxDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 11, 31)

Comment: https://angular-hzfeq3.stackblitz.io  .. Hi Koga ..Please check this link .. Do u know how disable the year popup in the top .. coz you can see except current year rest all the years are disabled .. so no point of showing all the years

Comment: This might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595066/angular-material-7-datepicker-disable-multi-year-view